# How were the 2014 Gamora and OG Nebula able to travel to the present in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, time-travel, avengers-endgame

How were the 2014 Gamora and OG Nebula able to travel to the present? From the movie, we know that for you need two thing for time travel: Pym particles and Time-Space GPS or the Time Gateway (like Thanos traveling to the present time with his ship and army). But the Time-Space GPS of the original Nebula was clearly seen being taken from her by the 2014 Nebula and she then traveled to the present with it.

Then, after Thanos's attack on the Avengers Compound the OG Nebula and 2014 Gamora also travel back to the present to fight the 2014 Nebula. How were they able to do this without the Time-Space GPS? Did I miss something?

Comment: With her knowledge of the time GPS and access to a pym particle, Thanos was able to easily recreate both technologies

Comment: 2014 Gamora and OG Nebula were both on Thanos’ ship.

Comment: @Valorum OP has no trouble with Thanos’ jump.

Answer (score 5):

There's a couple of points, one of which was sort-of added by the director afterward. Here's the timeline

1. Nebula23 travels to 2014, where she is captured by Nebula14 and Thanos14
2. Nebula14 is able to pull Nebula23's memories and learn about Thanos23 getting his wish and why she's there in the past
3. Thanos14 sends Nebula14 back to 2023, using the system Nebula23 was supposed to use. We'll come back to this
4. Nebula14 opens the portal wider and pulls Thanos14 and his massive ship into 2023

**Gamora14 and Nebula23 were on Thanos14's ship**

This is how both of them were in 2023. They both traveled with Thanos14's ship. Nebula14 was somehow able to lock onto the ship and pull it into the future. This bypassed the need for a GPS.

**Thanos14 has a guy who reverse-engineered the Pym Particle**

This ties into plot point #3. [Ebony Maw](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ebony_Maw/Cosmic_Time_Heist) (2014 version) made more Pym Particles (the movie never explained this). From [Joe Russo, the director](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bj0it4/joe_russos_qa_about_the_plot_of_avengers_endgame/?ref_source=embed&ref=share)

> Q: How did Thanos bring his army to the future?
>
> A: There is a guy called Maw in his army, he was a great wizard. Thanos himself was a brilliant genius as well. Those two easily reverse engineered and mass produced Pym Particles.